# NSXMLParser can not parse special characters (german & french)

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, special-characters, nsxmlparser

I am working on an App, which makes a search on a private server and shows the results to the user. The problem is NSXLParser can not parse the special german and french characters. For example: it should be:(Geschäftsführer) -> what i get is: (äftsführer)

How can i fix this ?

here is my code:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"results"])
    {
        currentJob = [SearchResult alloc];
    }

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"jobTitle"])
    {
        currentJob.jobTitle = currentNodeContent;
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"location"])
    {
        currentJob.shortAddress = currentNodeContent;
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"companyName"])
    {
        currentJob.employer = currentNodeContent;
    }

    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"results"])
    {
        [self.jobs addObject:currentJob];
        currentJob = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated...
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give a link to the XML file you are parsing?

Comment: also your `foundCharacters` method is wrong - you can get more than one call to this function even for a single string value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foundCharacters` method should append the string to a NSMutableString object, because it can be called multiple times for a single value. In `didStartElement`, initialize a NSMutableString object (let's call it `elementContentString`), then do this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)chars
{
    [self.elementContentString appendString:chars];
}
```

And in your `didEndElement` you can get the content as a string. Note that you should make a non-mutable copy of it (so you don't overwrite it with the next element), using `[NSString stringWithString:self.elementContentString]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the following code and it works now.    if(!elementContentString)
        elementContentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [elementContentString appendString:string];

Comment: I have a ´ character that is causing my parser to stop.  How do I handle that?  My foundCharacters method looks just like the one @kuba suggested.